# URLSession is making a GET request instead of a POST request

Tags: node.js, swift, heroku

So I'm trying to make a simple POST request in Swift. I'm not passing in any JSON in the request. I'm just trying to make the request by hitting a URL and passing in a param.

Swift side

```
class UpdateNotificationUsername: Identifiable {
    
    var supporter_id:String = ""
    init(supporter_id:String?) {
        if let supporter_id = supporter_id {
            self.supporter_id = supporter_id
        }
    }
    
    
    func save() {
        
        var components = URLComponents()
        components.scheme = "https"
        components.host = "hiphopvolume.com"
        components.path = "/setNotificationUsername/\(supporter_id)"
        
        
        
        let url = (components.url?.absoluteString)!
        
        guard let requestUrl = URL(string: url) else {
            fatalError("URL is not correct!")
            
        }
        var request = URLRequest(url: requestUrl)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            
            if let response = response {
                print("notif username response \(response)")
            }
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]
                    print("notif username result \(result)")
                } catch {
                    print("notif username err \(error)")
                }
            }
            
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Node JS

```
const updateNotificationSupporterUsername = async (request, response) => {
    const id = request.params.supporter_id;
     
    try {
    let supporterResult = await db.pool.query(
        'SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE supporter_id = $1', 
        [id])

     if (supporterResult.rowCount > 0) {
       var options = {
       method: 'POST',
       url: 'https://dev-owihjaep.auth0.com/oauth/token',
       headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'},
       data: {
         grant_type: 'client_credentials',
         client_id: '<id>',
         client_secret: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
         audience: 'https://dev-owihjaep.auth0.com/api/v2/'
      }
     };


     let accessTokenResponse = await axios.request(options)

     var auth0UserOptions = {
     method: 'GET',
     url: `https://dev-owihjaep.auth0.com/api/v2/users/${id}`,
     headers: {'content-type': 'application/json', authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessTokenResponse.data.access_token}
    };

    let auth0UserResponse = await axios.request(auth0UserOptions)

    console.log(auth0UserResponse + "auth0UserResponse")
    
    let supporterResult = await db.pool.query(
        'UPDATE notifications SET supporter_username = $1', 
        [auth0UserResponse.data.username])

    }

    response.status(200).send({message: "Success changing notification supporter_username"});
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
}
```

For some reason I see in my heroku logs that I'm making a GET request instead of a POST request when I test my `UpdateNotificationUsername.save()` function in Swift. It works when using my test URL but not my production. Although it works in Postman when hitting this production url.

Comment: I'm not sure a POST is valid without an `httpBody` value. A POST is supposed to send data to the server, after all. Try adding something in the `httpBody` field.

Comment: Yeah, I tried adding some empty JSON to the httpBody and it's still making a GET request.

Comment: This bit should set up a POST request: `request.httpMethod = "POST"`

Comment: It was working on my Test url. Not with my production url though

Comment: Have you tried using a tool like Charles or Postman to capture the outgoing request and verify that it is going out as a GET?

Comment: Yeah, it works on Postman

Comment: So I changed my methods to a PUT request and it worked. Thanks